# Mac OS X Python ctypes cdll error: image not found

Tags: python, macos, ctypes

I'm a beginner in Python. When I try to load an external DLL(which was compiled in Windows by other people) as following:

```
from ctypes import *
import cv2, cv as cv

PainterRender = CDLL('/Users/gulilin/Desktop/DLL/PainterRenderDll')
```

An error occurred as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gulilin/Desktop/Project/DLL Test.py", line 7, in <module>
  PainterRender = CDLL('/Users/gulilin/Desktop/DLL/PainterRenderDll') 
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/gulilin/Desktop/DLL/PainterRenderDll, 6): image not found
```

Can anyone tell me what's the matter?

Comment: I think you said what the matter is: "compiled in Windows by other people". I don't see anything in the ctypes docs which implies you can use it on a Mac to load a Windows DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared libraries (e.g., Windows DLLs) are like compiled binary executables: they only run on the platform for which they were compiled. ctypes can and will not translate between the various binary formats and calling conventions on different platforms. You will have to recompile the DLL as a Mac OS shared library (.dylib, I think).